# Swap on LVM vs swapfile on encrypted system

Tags: encryption, swap, lvm

I run Ubuntu 18.04 with full encryption. i have 1GB swap partition (default setting from installation), but now i can see it's not enough, i need much more.

I can see that increasing LVM swap partition size is not an easy task (unmounting partition / and decreasing size? and then increasing partition with swap). so i created additional /swapfile on root / partition.

**Are there any drawbacks with this solution ?**

my config now:

```
swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-2 partition 980M 980M   -2
/swapfile file       10G 4,3G   -3

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         13G        176M        1,1G        1,7G        580M
Swap:           10G        5,2G        5,8G
```

Comment: Since the root `/` is also encrypted. There should be no security concern. When the system boots if both the swap file and the swap partitions are recognized then I guess it should be fine.

Comment: i'm worried that maybe that's not most optimal/fastest way?
(system runs on SSD and i7 8th gen)

Comment: Why do you think you need more swap (I may end up agreeing with you...). Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: because i run Chrome (with many cards), IntelliJ Idea, Docker (with 6 containers java containers and Localstack), React dev server minimum...
...and 16GB is not enough

Comment: free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G         13G        176M        1,1G        1,7G        580M
Swap:           10G        5,2G        5,8G

Comment: and it looks like this 11GB of swap is sometimes not enough, i'll increase it to 20GB